# Can I force a TabControl's TabPages to resize *before* they're selected?

Tags: .net, winforms

I've just discovered that TabPages don't resize with a TabControl until *after* they're selected. This is a big problem for me because I have a panel that's anchored on all four edges and shared – by setting its `Parent` property – between two of several pages on a TabControl that is fill-docked to a resizable form. So, if I select a tab that *never* contains the panel, resize the form, and then select a tab that *will* contain it but doesn't presently, the panel doesn't get resized.

I've found that fill-docking the panel rather than anchoring it works okay, but I'd rather avoid that if at all possible, as the shared panel doesn't extend to the edges of the pages and its size can vary, so I'd have to mess around with the padding size of each page rather than simply altering the panel's size.

I've tested this in both VB and C# and they both behave the same way. I thought the solution given for [this known bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934) might do the trick, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Is there anything else I can do, such as force the pages to resize, to get around this problem?

**EDIT** – Steps to reproduce this in VS 2010:

- Add a TabControl to a resizable form, fill-dock it and add a third tab.
- Add a Panel to the 3rd tab, leaving plenty of space at the sides, anchor it to all four edges and set its BackColor to something different than the tabPage's so you can see it at runtime.
- Add this line of code to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

*VB*

```
If TabControl1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then Panel1.Parent = TabControl1.SelectedTab
```

*C#*

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex > 0) panel1.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
```

- Run/debug the form and resize it whilst the 1st tab is selected.
- Select the 2nd tab – you will see the panel hasn't resized.

Comment: The only difference I can imagine between fill docking and anchoring is the that in docking, order of controls added to a parent determine final rendering.
you may want to provide some code to make in available for us to recreate the error.

Comment: @Maziar I've edited the post to add simple instructions to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Understand in this situation it is a problem for you but in general I like that a TabControl does not render if it is not in view.

Comment: A simple workaround would be to put it on the first tabpage and set its Visible property to false.  Then just set Visible to True in the event handler.

Comment: @Hans It's not a 'once-only' problem, it occurs *every* time the form is resized while a tab that doesn't share the panel is selected and then selecting the panel-displaying tab that it isn't presently on.

Comment: Well, you didn't post a very good snippet then.

Comment: @Hans I thought I'd explained that in the final sentence of the first paragraph, sorry if I wasn't clearer. Nevertheless your suggestion has given me a workaround. I just have to *always* set the panel's parent to the selected tab and hide it on the ones I don't want to display it on. So please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround Hans Passant suggested I put the panel on the first TabPage (hidden) then set its Visible property in the event handler. As I explained, that wouldn't *quite* work – as it isn't just a "once-only" problem at start up; it occurs *whenever* the form is resized while a non-panel-displaying tab is selected, then selecting the panel-displaying tab that doesn't currently contain the panel – but it did point me in the right direction for the answer. Which is to set the panel's Visible property according to which tab is selected and ***always*** move the panel to the selected tab, regardless of whether the panel is displayed on it – EG:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Panel1.Visible = (TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage2) OrElse (TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage3)
    Panel1.Parent = TabControl1.SelectedTab
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, see [C# Winforms Tabpage Size and ClientSize wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56242122/2505186):
I created an `UserControl` that contains a `TabControl`. The content on the `TabPage`s is arranged based on the width of the `TabPage`, but the queried TabPage's `Size`, `ClientSize` and `DisplayRectangle.Size` are wrong as long as the TabPage hasn't been shown at least once. You have discovered the same, as you already wrote in your question.

**What I tried, all without success:**

- forcing the creation of the handle of each `TabPage`
- programmatically selecting each `TabPage`
- setting `visible = true` on each `TabPage`
- calling `PerformLayout` on each `TabPage`
- some other stuff that I don't remember any more

I even tried to find out what .net does internally and how to work around it in order to force the update of each TabPage, but I gave up on that because it was too complicated and time-consuming.

**What finally worked:**
My further analysis was adding debug-prints in my `UpdateLayout` function (called by the UC's `Layout` event), printing the `Size`, `ClientSize` and `DisplayRectangle.Size` of the TabControl and each TabPage. And suddenly my UC behaved as desired.
The queries of these values obviously trigger some .net functions that update the TabPages. Further tests show, that **querying the `TabControl.DisplayRectangle.Size` in the UC's `Layout` event is sufficient**, so you have to add just 1 line to your code:

```
var oSize = i_oTabControl.DisplayRectangle.Size;
```

and avoid that it's probably optimized away by the compiler:

```
[MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization | MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void TabControlForceUpdateOfTabpageSize (this TabControl i_oTabControl)
{
  if (i_oTabControl == null)
    return;
  var oSize = i_oTabControl.DisplayRectangle.Size;
}
```

**I have to admit that it maybe does not work in your situation, because I have also seen it failing in another test project. I am still searching for the reason.**

*Notice: Tests and Development were done in VS 2015 Update 3, using .Net 4.6. Solution is confirmed to be working in Debug and Release build.*

---

***Edit:***
I have spent some more hours on testing my solution. I also debugged into the .net source code again and finally found what roughly is happening there.

My solution worked because of a combination of different reasons:

1. The `TabControl` is placed inside a `UserControl`.
2. The used size of the `UserControl` is different from the size in which it was designed. This causes the `Layout` event of the UC to be raised.
3. The size change happens in `InitializeComponent()`, which means the UC has no parent yet.
4. On the respective `TabPage` I am not using it's own size, but the size of the `SelectedTab`, because I already found that the sizes of the not-visible tabpages are not updated properly, and all TabPages have the same size (`AutoScroll = false`).
5. The controls on the tabpages are placed programmatically and not via anchoring, using the size of the selected tabpage (see 4.)

The working principle is as follows:

- The target is to force the layout of the `TabControl` and it's `TabPage`s.
- This will only be done, if it is actually visible, see ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged()`.
- The TabPage or TabControl only is visible, if itself is set to visible and all parents are visible, see `Control.GetVisibleCore()`. If the Control is added to a form, the form becomes visible when it is shown, therefore the Control is invisible when the form's ctor is running. But if the control was not added to the form yet, the form's invisibility becomes irrelevant, because it's not the Controls's parent.

Now you're gonna say: "But my form *is* visible, so it should work."
Well, yes. In my situation, the UserControl was placed on a not selected TabPage of another TabControl, which means the UC's parent was not visible. But the UC did not have a parent when it's size was changed (see 2. and 3.), and the workaround in the UC's `Layout` event could force an update of the `TabControl` and the selected `TabPage`. And if the workaround was even present in the `Layout` events of the `TabControl` and all `TabPage`s, then all tabpages had the correct size values (at least after some cycles).

The workaround could also work for you with a little trick (tested):
Remove the TabControl from its parent, cycle through all tabpages and add it back to the parent later.

```
var oParent = tabctrlU.Parent;
oParent.Controls.Remove (tabctrlU);
var tabStart = tabctrlU.SelectedTab;
foreach (TabPage tab in tabctrlU.TabPages)
  tabctrlU.SelectedTab = tab;
tabctrlU.SelectedTab = tabStart;
oParent.Controls.Add (tabctrlU);
```

This enables the update-forcing.
But: It does NOT work for future resizing on the invisible tabs. Now, every resize triggers the `Layout` event, so you could add some code there. Actually I would not remove and re-add the tabcontrol every time, this would be stupid. So I have to admit that this solution is not well applicable to your case. But you (and others) now have some ideas how to deal with it.

As you already have found a solution yourself: If you did not want to move the `Panel1` to the first TabPage, the you could remember the size and position of the `Panel1` and its parent TabPage in the ctor, and resize the `Panel1` programmatically according to the (new) size of the selected TabPage after it has been moved to that page.