# C# Winforms Tabpage Size and ClientSize wrong

Tags: c#, winforms, size, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have created a user control that contains a TabControl with 2 TabPages. The position of the child controls on both TabPages is adapted programmatically in the `Layout` event of the user control.
The problem is, that the 2nd TabPage has not been drawn yet when the event is called and therefore this TabPage has a wrong Size and ClientSize.

How can I work around that?
I tried a loop with `var oHandle = tabpage.Handle` and `tabctrl.SelectedTab = each tabpage` already to force the creation of the TabPages, but this hasn't helped.

**EDIT #1**
I have found a first "bug" which is observed in the VS Designer:
When you drag a `TabControl` on the Form and then resize the it in the Designer, the size of the currently visible `TabPage` is updated. But the sizes of all other tabpages are not; they stay the same until any additional change is done on any control (tested!).
I admit that this situation is quite uncommon, so the sizes usually are updated, but nonetheless in my opinion it's a design flaw in the `TabControl`.

This design flaw becomes very relevant when the TabControl is resized at runtime! Here's a minimal example for repro (without UC, just a TabControl in a Form):

Form1.cs:

```
public Form1 ()
{
  InitializeComponent ();

  Debug.Print ("ctor before resize");
  Debug.Print ("TC: " + tabControl1.Size);
  Debug.Print ("T1: " + tabPage1.Size);
  Debug.Print ("T2: " + tabPage2.Size);

  tabControl1.Size = tabControl1.Size + new Size (10, 10);
  Debug.Print ("ctor after resize");
  Debug.Print ("TC: " + tabControl1.Size);
  Debug.Print ("T1: " + tabPage1.Size);
  Debug.Print ("T2: " + tabPage2.Size);
}

private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ... same as ctor, prints adapted ("load before/after resize)
}

private void Form1_Layout (object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.Print ("Layout");
}

private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ... same as ctor, prints adapted ("button before/after resize)
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs:  (irrelevant parts removed)

```
private void InitializeComponent ()
{
  this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl ();
  this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage ();
  this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage ();
  this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button ();
  this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout ();
  this.SuspendLayout ();
  //
  this.tabControl1.Controls.Add (this.tabPage1);
  this.tabControl1.Controls.Add (this.tabPage2);
  this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (300, 120);
  //
  this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (292, 91);
  //
  this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (292, 91);
  //
  this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler (this.button1_Click);
  //
  this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF (96F, 96F);
  this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
  this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size (384, 262);
  this.Controls.Add (this.tabControl1);
  this.Controls.Add (this.button1);
  this.Load += new System.EventHandler (this.Form1_Load);
  this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout (false);
  this.ResumeLayout (false);
}
private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Debug prints:

```
ctor before resize
TC: {Width=300, Height=120}
T1: {Width=292, Height=91}
T2: {Width=292, Height=91}
Layout
Layout
ctor after resize
TC: {Width=310, Height=130}
T1: {Width=292, Height=91}    (wrong)
T2: {Width=292, Height=91}    (wrong)

Load before resize
TC: {Width=310, Height=130}
T1: {Width=302, Height=101}    (now correct because updated after ctor)
T2: {Width=302, Height=101}    (now correct because updated after ctor)
Layout
Layout
Load after resize
TC: {Width=320, Height=140}
T1: {Width=312, Height=111}    (correct because visible)
T2: {Width=302, Height=101}    (wrong again)
Layout

(TabPage1 selected, TabPage2 is not updated)
button before resize
TC: {Width=320, Height=140}
T1: {Width=312, Height=111}
T2: {Width=302, Height=101}    (still wrong: TabPage2 HAS NOT BEEN UPDATED WHILE THE UI-THREAD WAS IDLE)
Layout
Layout
button after resize
TC: {Width=330, Height=150}
T1: {Width=322, Height=121}
T2: {Width=302, Height=101}    (even more wrong)

(TabPage1 selected, TabPage2 is not updated)
button before resize
TC: {Width=330, Height=150}
T1: {Width=322, Height=121}
T2: {Width=302, Height=101}    (still wrong)
Layout
Layout
button after resize
TC: {Width=340, Height=160}
T1: {Width=332, Height=131}
T2: {Width=302, Height=101}    (again more wrong)

(TabPage2 selected, now TabPage1 is not updated)
button before resize
TC: {Width=340, Height=160}
T1: {Width=332, Height=131}
T2: {Width=332, Height=131}    (now correct because visible)
Layout
Layout
button after resize
TC: {Width=350, Height=170}
T1: {Width=332, Height=131}    (now wrong)
T2: {Width=342, Height=141}    (still correct because visible)
```

Based on this behaviour, the only solution that I currently have is calling the `UpdateLayout()` function of my UC on every call of `tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged (..)`.

**EDIT #2**
The "solution" of Edit #1 does not work because:
If the TabPages have little width, the controls on the pages are arranged vertically, causing a greater height of the respective TabPage. The overall height of the UC depends on the height of the TabControl, whose height depends on all TabPages, so the `UpdateLayout()` needs to have correct sizes of all TabPages, otherwise the UC height would change again later when another tab is selected, but it should be correct already at design time.

Comment: Without seeing the code, a proper diagnosis is difficult.  However, most issues with the `TabPage` delayed control creation can be resolved can be resolved by setting its `Visible` property to true.  See [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119854/2592875) for more info; it is in VB, but the background info is the same as would be the logic.

Comment: @TnTinMn: you can reproduce it quite easily: create a new form, drag a TabControl on it (it'll have 2 Tabs by default) and change its size, and query the size of both Tabs in the form's ctor. You'll get different values although both Tabs belong to the same TabControl

Comment: Set the UC AutoScale to DPI and the same thing in the hosting Form. Measure again.

Comment: Note that the `Layout` event is called the first time before the UC constructor. The first time it's raised, all of the internal measures will be as the original, before the control is scaled. It will be raised again after `OnHandleCreated`. This time all the measures will be scaled (if the AutoScale mode is set to Font, for sure. Test it with `AutoScaleMode = None` or `Inherit` **You need to rebuild the UC's Project after**. It's sometimes necessary to replace the control on the Form).

Comment: @Jimi: I'm always using DPI, so this was already active in my test. I'll add a minimal example for repro.

Comment: @TnTinMn: You can see from my test that `Visible=true` will not work, because the failure even appears when the `TabControl` is visible already. The be sure, I have tested your proposal and confirmed to be not working.

Comment: If you resize the UC twice in the constructor, you bet the sizes are different: the Layout event is raised *before* the constructor. The fact that a TabControl renders its TabPages when they're shown is notorious as is the reason why this is done: you may have a lot of pages and a lot of child controls, rendering all at the same time is a costly (and not very useful) operation. But, one can just say *it's by design* an move on.

Comment: @Jimi Even if it's "by design", it does not give me a better solution than the workaround I'm using at the moment. The question remains: how can I force the update of the TabPages?

Comment: You probably you can do what (I think) everyone else does: work with the currently shown page, detect when a TabPage is about to be changed/show and do exactly what the TabControl does: render/layout the content before it becomes visible to the user. i.e., not preemptively.

Comment: "The position of the child controls on both TabPages is adapted programmatically in the Layout event of the user control." - If the positions of the TabPage's child controls is dependent on the size of the `TabPage`, then why not set those positions in the `TabPage.Layout` event (when the `AffectedProperty` = "Bounds") instead of the user control layout event?

Comment: @TnTinMn: great idea! Thanks!

Comment: @TnTinMn: actually there's a little problem with your idea (I'll keep it in mind for future use though): if the tabpage has little width, the controls are arranged vertically, causing a greater height on the respective tabpage. The overall height of the UC depends on the height of the tabcontrol, whose height depends on all tabpages, so the Layout() needs to have correct sizes of all tabpages, otherwise the UC height would change again later when another tab is selected.

Comment: The _idea_ is the proper one to layout each page in its respective layout event; the problem arises with the rather strange behavior that you want for its parent and the user control.  Also, are we discussing a design mode behavior or run-time behavior or both?

Comment: Note that only the bounds of the selected TabPage are changed when the TabControl is resized.  Assuming Width is now the controlling metric, you could update the bounds of the non-selected tabs on tabcontrol's resize event.  That will trigger a layout event for those tabs.  After that you can determine the tallest PreferredSize and then resize the tabcontrol accordingly.  You will need to makes sure that do not get into a recursive loop on TabControl Resize event.  Why not just enable scrolling for the TabPage?  It is a standard design feature.

Comment: @TnTinMn: I understand the idea, and this idea is good and correct. However, as you can see the behaviour that I want differs from that. But I found a solution, which creates a correctly sized UC already at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quite simple solution to get the correct size of the TabPages:

All TabPages belong to the same TabControl, thus all TabPages have the same size, no matter what the `Size` property of the respective TabPage says.
Additionally, there's allways one TabPage that reports the correct size, which is the currently selected TabPage.
Therefore the size of every TabPage is `TabControl.SelectedTab.Size`.

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately this does NOT work if the whole `TabControl` is not visible, maybe because it's placed on a `TabPage` of another `TabControl` which is currently not selected.
However, I found another solution, which I posted as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56427684/2505186) on this question [Can I force a TabControl's TabPages to resize *before* they're selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11276107/2505186), which actually is more or less a duplicate question of mine.
The relevant part of that answer:

> [...]
>   You have to add just 1 line to your code:
>
> ```
> var oSize = i_oTabControl.DisplayRectangle.Size;
> ```
>
> and avoid that it's probably optimized away by the compiler:
>
> ```
> [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization | MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
> public static void TabControlForceUpdateOfTabpageSize (this TabControl i_oTabControl)
> {
>   if (i_oTabControl == null)
>     return;
>   var oSize = i_oTabControl.DisplayRectangle.Size;
> }
> ```
>
> [...]